# How to call php script to update database following ajax call to refresh a list

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

In my app, I'm showing the list of friends(#LIST) being tagged in a picture using jQuery ajax. The list is being populated from the database entries.

Now when I tag a new friend, I need to update the entry in the database. And, then refresh the list of friends(#LIST).

I'm trying to update the list in the database by calling a php script using form.submit(), then I redirect the script to the original page. But, I actually don't want to refresh the whole page but just #LIST.

I'm not getting, how can I run the php script to update database, which after ending, would refresh my #LIST using ajax.

My code looks like below:

```
 // JQuery
 $("#list").load("taggedfriends.php");
 $("#list_of_friends").load("facebookfriends.php");

 //HTML
 <div id="list"></div> // list of tagged friends
 <form id="form_update" action="updatevalues.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="list_of_friends"></div> // my facebook friends
    <button type="submit" id="btn_update">Update</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Whats your code like at the moment? I think the simple answer is just passing the new list from the database back to the jQuery ajax call, and getting that to redo the list (or append new items onto it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, use a jquery ajax function, and in its callback, refresh the #list element. that should do, what you need.

```
    $.ajax({
      url : 'your_php_script.php',
      type: 'POST'
      data : data, //json_object to send as a parameter
      success : function(returned_data){
       //refresh #list
      }
     });
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer. But, as I'm a newbie with JQuery and Ajax, could you illustrate more.
success : function(returned_data){
       //refresh #list
      }
Here, for refreshing #list, how do i re-write the <div>? I guess, not another ajax call.

Comment: I gave you the construct for that. here's the ajax API http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/ this has an example too.